# Use set equalities to prove $A−(B\cup C) = (A−B)∩(A−C)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

This is what needs to be proved: $$A−(B\cup C) = (A−B)∩(A−C)$$
I've tried working from both sides, but have gotten further from working with the left. Here's my attempt:$$A \cap (B \cup C)^{'}$$ $$A \cap (B^{'} \cap C^{'})$$ $$(A \cap B^{'}) \cap C^{'}$$ $$(A-B)-C$$

Comment: Are you sure that's what you want to prove?

Comment: MADE A TYPO ORIGINALLY, has been edited. it was $A- (B\cap C)$ but should've been $A- (B\cup C)$

Comment: It's one of De Morgan's laws.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the LHS is a subset of $A$, we can introduce another intersection with $A$ without affecting the result. Continuing from the third line:
$$(A\cap B')\cap C'=(A\cap B')\cap(A\cap C')=(A-B)\cap(A-C)$$

Comment: please see edited problem

Comment: @BrynBurns Now accept and upvote my answer!

Answer (score 0):

You have the following, $A-(B\cup C) = A \cap (B\cup C)^c = A \cap (B^c\cap C^c) = (A \cap B^c) \cap (A\cap C^c) = (A-B)\cap (A-C)$

Comment: please see edited problem

Comment: I'll edit my post